# Is this an insect? Which one?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this animal, which I suspect it's an insect, on the floor of a kitchen in Spain some days ago. It's about 8-10 mm long. I don't think I've ever seen it before. What is it?

[image: Back]

[image: Front]

Comment: This looks like a silverfish (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish )

Answer (score 4):

It is a [**silverfish**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish). It is a 'basic lineage' in the insect class. You'll find it [here on OneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/life/@Zygentoma=159370?vis=spiral#x146,y-546,w5.0605).

Silverfish are considered household pests although I don't think they spread disease nor cause much damage (thanks to @WilliamBligh for his comment). They typically live in the canalization (bathroom, kitchen) or anywhere that is wet enough. In a building, they may be hard to get rid of as they can easily move from one apartment to another. You have to keep your place very clean and eventually use toxins such as Permethrin or Deltamethrin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: While they are considered a "household pest", they are to the best of my knowledge not harmful. Even contamination of food is, again to the best of my knowledge, undocumented (but sometimes assumed). If they are not present in large numbers, I would advise not to poison them. 

Edit to add: pyrethroids are hardly "specific" toxines.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your comment. I edited the answer accordingly.